# Question about ARMA order in the univariate GARCH model specification

Tags: time-series, arima, stationarity, garch

Would it be correct to say that the series is stationary in the below code, since only ARMA order is specified?

```
uspec1 <- ugarchspec(mean.model = list(armaOrder = c(2,1)))
```

And, if it is so, then, if my return series is non-stationary, should I estimate ARMA order after differencing the series to make it stationary first as an input in the code above?

Answer (score -1):

You do not automatically impose stationarity on a time series by fitting a model. You, as the time series analyst, must first make a relevant transformation, or include a trend component into your mean structure, in order to deal with the non-stationarity.

Comment: I agree with Patrick that this answer would be better formulated as a comment asking for clarification. Also, "I think you are confused" is really unnecessary.

Comment: @akkp I think I was not clear. I am not imposing stationarity. I have used ADF and PP tests on the return series to find that the return series is non-stationary at level but becomes stationary after second differencing. Now, since the GARCH model specification code requires armaorder as an input, should I be inputting the order of my differenced series?